# Why can't I read JSON files in certain parts of my project?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am working on an angular project and want to edit a JSON value based on the key of the key value pair on the click of a button to match user input from a textfield. I am working on this project with others who did the heavy lifting so a lot of it is just learning the structure. I try to use

`const fs = require("fs");`

then

`fs.readFileSync`

to get into the file.
This is what other users have done on other parts of the projects but when I do it I get an error saying TypeError:
fs.readFileSync is not a function, or it doesn't recognize fs at all.
I have tried adding things like

```
    "browser": {
        "fs": false,
        "path": false,
        "os": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "stream": false,
        "http": false,
        "tls": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "https": false,
        "net": false
    }
```

to my package.json files, both in my module and in the root project, but nothing seems to be working.

Fs works in some parts of the project that others have worked on but I can't get it to work on mine and I can't figure out how to edit the JSON values based on the user input.
I know this is a vague question but does anyone have any ideas or follow up questions I could answer that might lead to something?

Comment: can you show the code you have tried with `readFileSync` so we can debug? If you are calling `fs` in a file that will be ran in the browser this will not work as `fs` is a node standard library

Comment: fs is not available in browser, only node. It makes no sense to use it in an Angular app meant for the browser.